# gtsummary tables include striping by default in latest update, can it be turned off?

Tags: gtsummary

The gtsummary update now includes striping in all tables in a rendered html document. I don’t want striping, but cannot find a solution that works to turn it off.

I tried modifying via css and converting the table to a gt table.

Comment: FYI gtsummary tables by default are printed with gt defaults. To change the striping you'll need to convert the table to gt, and use get functions to change the striping